# Failed opening required '/db_connect.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear')

Tags: php, pear

so I made this android application connecting to database, and I got this error in php

Warning: require_once(/db_connect.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\AppServ\www\android_connect\viewAllWeb.php on line 47

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/db_connect.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\AppServ\www\android_connect\viewAllWeb.php on line 47

that particular php is supposed to call data from my database and display it as a table

the thing is, I tried it in my computer (say it's comp1)in my localhost (with wamp, no PEAR, register global off) and it works, no error whatsoever even in my application

but when i put it in another computer (lets say comp2)which I want to put as a server (appserv, PEAR, register global on) it shows that error

any idea what this is about then? I tried turning register global on and off in comp2 like some suggestion in google, to no avail. Does it have something to do with comp1 not having pear or something?  Because i did my coding in comp1

the path in comp1 is C/wamp/www/android_connect
the path in comp2 is C/AppServ/www/android_connect

Thanks

```
        <?php
    require "db_connect.php";
    //require "get_all_products.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Daftar Barang</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body,td,th {
    font-family: Calibri, Verdana, Arial;
}
body {
    background-color: #000;
}
-->
</style></head>
<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table width="80%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">
      <h1><strong>Daftar Barang</strong></h1>
    </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table width="98%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">


        <table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <th>Serial Number</th>
            <th>Label</th>
            <th>Jenis</th>
            <th>Merk</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Departemen</th>
            <th>Kondisi</th>
            </tr>
        <?php
            $response = array();


// include db connect class
require_once '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY label") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $product = array();
        $product["SN"] = $row["SN"];
        $product["label"] = $row["label"];
        $product["jenis"] = $row["jenis"];
        $product["merk"] = $row["merk"];
        $product["user"] = $row["user"];
        $product["dept"] = $row["dept"];
        $product["cond"] = $row["cond"];

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["SN"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["label"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["jenis"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["merk"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["user"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["dept"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["cond"] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";


    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    //echo json_encode($response);

} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}





        ?>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is db_connect.php in the same folder as viewAllWeb.php?

Comment: yep, all of them in one folder

Answer (score 2):

Try using either `require_once("db_connect.php")` or `require_once("./db_connect.php");`